# USB partition problem

Tags: partitioning, usb

So i had a USB drive that i used to install Ubuntu here and there. It started having problems a little while ago. Now its like this: [USB partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnSKj.png)
When i try to erase a partition i get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DrAW.png).
What can I do to solve it?
I never did any partitioning on my own.

Sorry i cannot post pictures till i have 10 reputation so i used links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to reformat the USB use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

If you are trying to create a bootable USB [(look here)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).